# Spring boot postgres pagination if result is less than page size

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, pagination

I want to have a pagination on my spring boot with postgres application . I have created this query in my mapper :

> 

```
SELECT
  a.*
FROM dct.dynamic_dictionary_entry a
WHERE a.dict_code = UPPER(#{dictCode})
  AND  a.variant = UPPER(#{variant})
OFFSET CASE WHEN (SELECT
  COUNT(1)
  FROM dct.dynamic_dictionary_entry a
  WHERE a.dict_code = UPPER(#{dictCode})
  AND  a.variant = UPPER(#{variant}) ) > #{pageSize}
  THEN #{pageNo}
    ELSE
      (SELECT
      COUNT(1)
      FROM dct.dynamic_dictionary_entry a
      WHERE a.dict_code = UPPER(#{dictCode})
      AND  a.variant = UPPER(#{variant}) )
        END
ROWS FETCH NEXT #{pageSize} ROWS ONLY
```

but I am getting the error below.

> org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not set parameters for mapping: ParameterMapping{property='variant', mode=IN, javaType=class java.lang.Object, jdbcType=null, numericScale=null, resultMapId='null', jdbcTypeName='null', expression='null'}. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null for parameter #10 with JdbcType null . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different configuration property. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null for parameter #10 with JdbcType null . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different configuration property. Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 10, number of columns: 9.

note that I have a previous offset like this

> OFFSET #{pageNo} ROWS FETCH NEXT #{pageSize} ROWS ONLY

But it does not return any result if for example result is only two and pageNo is set to 5 and pageSize is set to 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up using this query

> SELECT
> a.*
> FROM dct.dynamic_dictionary_entry a
> WHERE a.dict_code = UPPER(#{dictCode})
> AND  a.variant = UPPER(#{variant})
> OFFSET
> case when #{pageSize} >= (SELECT
> count(1)
> FROM dct.dynamic_dictionary_entry a
> WHERE a.dict_code = UPPER(#{dictCode})
> AND  a.variant = UPPER(#{variant}) )
> then 0
> else #{pageNo}
> end
> ROWS FETCH NEXT #{pageSize} ROWS ONLY